# How can I extract data behind a login page using import.io

Tags: import.io

I need to crawl some data that sits behind a login page. To be able to scrap it I need a tool that is able to login and then crawl the pages behind it. Is it possible to do this behind import.io?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: yes, it is.

Longer version:
 There are at least two ways, both require you to sign up and download the desktop app (all free)

Extractor version (simpler):
Point the browser to the page where the login is. Login normally, then train your API to extract the data you need. The downside of using this method is that it will only work as long as you are logged in. If you want import.io to login for you you'll need the..

Authenticated version:
As above, but create an authenticated API. This will record for login procedure and execute it for you every time you execute the API

Comment: To clarify.  This will create an API that will allow you to parse data from a HTML page that sits behind a login.  You will have to create the crawler logic yourself.

Comment: [The authenticated API is gone for now.](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/763143-we-re-parking-authenticated-api%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs-for-now) I also tried the Extractor, but when you turn on extraction the API comes in and the API doesn't have my login credentials so I was logged out.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore : the "Desktop version" is now legacy (unavailable for download).

Comment: Whats the point in having a scrapper that can not handle logins? Most of the valuable data is password protected

Answer (score 2):

Since the chosen answer doesn't work anymore :( I recommend [Cloudscrape](http://cloudscrape.com). You will get a free trial with 20 hours of crawling and/or scraping if you sign up. For data behind a login you will need a scraper.

#### Handy tutorials

[Tutorial for logging in with scraper.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tLvI2YDA8s)

[Tutorial for pagination.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jSfG8g8uEI)